# Which approach is better for using an SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dataset

I'm working on a project that needs to read some diffrent query from database and after making lots of changes in data decide to save it on the server or not.

Right now I'm using linq to sql but the problem is that, if I want to submit changes in the end, I can't make diffrent query on tables, because my changes will be lost.

So is there any way to make an in memory database, then manipulate data, and finally save data on the server?

What would be the best approach for this kinda cases?

Comment: could you explain little more. what type of manipulation will be done on your data?

Comment: It's not clear why the changes would be lost.  If you query the LINQ context, manipulate the objects, and apply the changes on the context, how are the changes lost?  Perhaps as a general answer to your question you might want to look into Entity Framework, which is pretty much where Microsoft is focusing ORM development.  The principle is the same... get the objects from the data, manipulate them, persist the changes.

Comment: Yes You are Right, actually problem is that i cant query inserted data before submit changes on the server in linq to sql. is ther any better way to query newly inserted data before saving on server? is it possible by entity? thanks for your fast answer by the way, im new in this site.

Comment: You can query inserted data by `context.GetChangeSet().Inserts`. But you better give a concrete example because it's hard to give any solid advice on this general description.

Comment: yes thats helps alot, but as a concrete example:
i have a PRODUCT table with some records, i make new record like
PRODUCT.NAME="blabla"
PRODUCT.NO="1234"
then call DB.PRODUCT.insertonsubmit(PRODUCT)

how is possible to query all records plus this newly inserted record before submiting to server?

Comment: Your data is not inserted until it's saved on the server.  Until then, it is probably persisted in the form of variables in your application code, which makes them accessible to your application.